# Can I reorder the execution of apache modules when it processes http requests?

Tags: apache

We have an apache server running an application, we use auth_jwt module to validate the token coming in the request, and we use tile module to serve the request.

What is happening is, the tile module evaluates first and get the data from the cache, then the auth_jwt evaluates the token after that.

The problem is a lot of requests are coming with an invalid token, so I want the auth_jwt module to evaluate first to save the effort of the tile module.

I tried this:

```
a2enconf mod_authnz_jwt
a2enconf mod_tile
```

hoping that the order of enabling the module will be the same as the order of evaluating but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure how apache order the modules.

any ideas how to order the execution of the modules ?